# Passing multiple values to a parameter in Snowflake table function

Tags: function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to pass multiple values to a parameter in Snowflake Table function?
For example, if we have country parameter - can we pass multiple values to the country and then use the parameter in the query using IN clause?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `ARRAY` to package multiple parameters into one, eg

```
SELECT ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('FR', 'IN', 'UK', 'NO') My_Multiparam_Array;
```

If you don't have scalar values, but eg. a table column, you have to construct the `ARRAY` with `ARRAY_AGG()`.

Then use `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` instead of `IN`:

```
SELECT ARRAY_CONTAINS('FR'::VARIANT, My_Multiparam_Array); -- True if 'FR' is in the array
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways that you could achieve this, here is the one that came to mind:

```sql
create or replace function get_ids(FirstNames Array)
returns table (id number)
as $$
 select "CustomerKey"::Number 
 from dim_customer
 where lower("FirstName") in (
    select value from table(flatten(input=>FirstNames))
  )
$$
;

select * 
from table(get_ids(array_construct('jon', 'ruben', 'simon', 'shannon')));
```